# Javascript/Jquery to run function when browser width change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, width

I'm creating a mobile website, but right now client insist on using an original website which is non responsive. That means I will be having two website under the same domain.

Now what I need to do is compare user screen size when loading the webpage and redirect them to the right website.

I can resolve this using javascript below:

```
  if($(window).width() <= 760){ 
    document.location = "https://maps.google.com.my/";
    alert('mobile ver');//goto mobile version
  }
```

but there is another problem, what if the person is browsing the website using

1.smaller screen(computer screen) at first then later decide to maximize the browser screen?

or

1. switch from portrait view to landscape view, (which has a longer width...)

Is there a function that could trigger every time the browser width change?

Comment: You should really look at media queries in CSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to call to your function inside resize event

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
 //call to your function and check the window width
 });
```

Comment: Great answer! but how do I add a function like: 
function abrir() {
  $('#sidebar').css('display','initial');
}
It's showing abrir is not a function on console

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider having a single website that uses media queries -- as mentioned in @mattytommo's comment -- to alter layout based on the screen width. I've developed a few websites now that have just one site for mobile, tablets, and desktops using media queries. It's occasionally awkward, but it saves having to have two different sites and thus double the maintenance burden.